# How to get multiply variables with mod_rewrite

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, apache2, config, virtualhost

How to make from `http://site.com/id555/forum666/thread777` this `http://site.com/#id=555#forum=666#thread=777`?
I have try this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/id([0-9]+)/?$ /#id=$1 [NC,NE,R=303]
RewriteRule ^/forum([0-9]+)/?$ /#forum=$1 [NC,NE,R=303]
RewriteRule ^/thread([0-9]+)/?$ /#thread=$1 [NC,NE,R=303]
```

But all what i get with it is `http://site.com/#id=555`, so i tried make it like this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(/(id|forum|thread)([0-9]+))+ #$2=$3 [NC,NE,N,R=303]
```

The result was `http://site.com/#thread=777` . A do not understand, how i must change the rule, to get it on the right way. I use it from the main config over `VirtualHost` section, because it is much like for me, but if you help me to get it worked with `.htaccess`, I would be make it this way.

**Important:** It can be any amount of variables in URL in any order.
Examples:

```
http://site.com/thread777/forum666
http://site.com/id555/thread777
http://site.com/forum666
http://site.com/id555/forum666/thread777/id333/id444/forum777
```

They all must be transformed this way like:

```
http://site.com/#thread=777#forum=666
http://site.com/#id=555#thread=777
http://site.com/#forum=666
http://site.com/#id555#forum=666#thread=777#id=333#id=444#forum=777
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your 2nd try was close.  How about this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(id|forum|thread)([0-9]+)(.*) $1#$2=$3$4 [N,NC,NE,R=303]
```

As in your rule, the N flag makes the rule repeat as often as needed until it's done.  At each iteration, it transforms the rightmost group of /id555 or whatever into #id=555.

`^(.*)` = leading groups, if any, that haven't been transformed yet

`/(id|forum|thread)([0-9]+)` = group being processed in this iteration

`(.*)` = trailing groups, if any, already processed

However I think that after this, the leading `/` may be gone, transformed to a `#`. So you may need to add it back in by following the above rule by

```
RewriteRule (.*) /$1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I needed. The second rule is not needed, because you drag / anytime with $1 at the front. Also on my server and browser does it no problem without `RewriteRule (.*) /$1`